# Modal Not Functioning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a modal to my website, yet such section is not functioning. The Id and data target have the same name while the scripts are assigned on the bottom side of the body section. What is exactly wrong, please?

Below is the code

```html
    <div class="pricing-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</button>
    </div>


    <section id="purchasemodal">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalHere" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<span class="sr-only">Close</span></span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Subscribe to Our Mailing List</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Simply enter your name and emil! Appriciate visiting my new Website. New notifications will be sent every time.</p>
                            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-name">Your First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-name" placeholder="Your First Name">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">Your Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="Your Email">

                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
                            </form>
                            <hr>
                            <p><small>By Providing the email your consent to recive occasinal promotional emails &amp; newsletters.</small></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--Bootsrap Javascript-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Wow JS-->
    <script src="js/wow/wow.min.js"></script>

    <!--magnific popup JS-->
    <script src="js/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Owl Carosel JS-->
    <script src="js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <!--Counter-->
    <script src="js/counter/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/counter/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

    <!--Easingr-->
    <script src="js/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <!--JS Script-->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Could you share the link of the page which having that issue, or add the CDN for those plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the required js and css files.

Here is your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/subhrajyoti21/bbps6jzq/

Please download the below files and add them to your HTML file.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In order for my modal to function, I have to resort back to an older Bootstrap version?

Comment: No you can use the latest one ... not a problem just add those files. It should work.

Comment: $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
}) What about this function?

Comment: Do you want to focus on a text field once the modal is open ? The function brings into focus the ID you provide.

Comment: No, I want it whenever the purchase button is clicked.

Comment: You can use it in the following way  
$('#purchase_button').on('click', function () { $('#myInput').focus() })